# C# What happens when you pass null to an optional argument

Tags: c#, string, function, parameters, optional-parameters

If I have a function with an optional argument like so:

```
public string testFunction (string arg1 = "Adam"){
    return "Hello " + arg1;
}
```

If I pass a null string to the function, will the function return:

"Hello Adam"

Or:

"Hello " (Hello *null*)

Comment: Try it out and report back. Hint: `null` is not a literal value, but it is a value.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel `null` most certainly *is* a literal value.

Comment: @Servy: yeah, I guess I was a little ambiguous. I meant to say that `null` does not represent a text representation of `null`.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple to just try out with a simple C# console application.

The answer is that `arg1` is `null`, and the output is `Hello`

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it currently setup, the default is "Adam", so you can call the function like so; `string mystring = testfunction();` and it will return "Hello Adam", anything you pass in, will replace Adam, including null.